# Can't get rid of splint warning "Field used before definition", "rvalue is used that may not be initialized to a value on some execution"

Tags: c, winapi, splint

I'm struggling to get rid of a splint warning for the following code:

```
void GetPrinterInfo(HANDLE hPrinter){
    PRINTER_INFO_4* pPrinterInfo = NULL;
    DWORD bytesNeeded;

    GetPrinter(hPrinter, 4, NULL, 0, &bytesNeeded);

    pPrinterInfo = malloc(bytesNeeded);

    if (GetPrinter(hPrinter, 4, (LPVOID)(pPrinterInfo), bytesNeeded, &bytesNeeded)){
        printf("Printer name: %S", pPrinterInfo->pPrinterName);
    }

    free(pPrinterInfo);
}
```

The warning is (on the "printf" line):

> Field pPrinterInfo->pPrinterName used before definition
>
> 1>    An rvalue is used that may not be initialized to a value on some
>   execution

Presumably it assumes that the `pPrinter` hasn't been populated yet. I have tried marking the header definition of `SetPrinter` with `/*@out@*/`s etc. but it doesn't help. I've tried a bunch of annotations inside the header file such as `/*@temp@*/`, `/*@dependent@*/` to no avail.

How do I sensibly let splint know that the pPrinter field is expected to be valid after a call to `GetPrinter`?

Comment: Possible workaround is to use `calloc` instead of `malloc`.  Assuming that splint understands what `calloc` does.

Comment: @user3386109 That worked! Didn't think that would be the problem. The GetPrinter definition should already have an `out` parameter so I'm surprised this makes any difference. So one would think that maybe I'm editing the wrong header file but I really do seem to be using the right one. May just use a `memset` instead so I don't have to use the goofy `calloc` function. Thank you, this will be fine for now. Unless someone comes up with a better solution I'll make this the answer later.

Comment: You can get rid of the warning by getting  rid of that `splint`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Splint actually works quite well for what I'm doing. It needs to be integrated into the build process and it needs to use XP-compatible WinDDK (so very old compiler). I have found it decent at detecting memory leaks etc. However it's hard to use and sometimes you run into difficult issues like the above.

Comment: How can static analysis detect memory leaks?  I do that using the [Debug Versions of Heap Allocation Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx) but your compiler might be too old to support those.

Comment: @PaulSanders With all the annotations is possible to do a lot with static analysis. The fact that you do dynamic analysis is not interesting to me; that's not what this question is about.

Comment: @Patrick OK, understood, I should learn to stop interfering in things that don't concern  me :)  Although the `pPrinterInfo` parameter is marked as `out`, the `LPVOID` cast may defeat that.  And `calloc` clearing the warning makes sense, since [splint knows that] it zeroes the allocated memory, which is probably good practise here anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still not clear why `SetPrinter` with the `out` annotation didn't work. However an acceptable workaround (from user3386109) is to just blank the memory so that splint treats it as initialized:

```
pPrinterInfo = malloc(bytesNeeded);

ZeroMemory(pPrinterInfo, bytesNeeded);

if (GetPrinter(hPrinter, 4, (LPVOID)(pPrinterInfo), bytesNeeded, &bytesNeeded)){
```

Where `ZeroMemory` is just an alias for `memset`.

This is not ideal, would be better if no extra actions were undertaken to fix this warning, however it will do for my case.